# jQuery Validation Plugin remote callback into form

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have a form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form"  name="form">
<p><label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name" value="" name="name" /></p>

<p><label for="uname">Username<input type="text" id="username" name="username" value=""/></p>
 </form>
```

Jquery with jqueryvalidationform:

```
var validator = $("#form").validate({  
    ignore: ':hidden',          

    rules: {
                name:{
                        required:true,
                        remote: {
                                type: "post",
                                url: "remote-file.php",
                                data: {
                                        username: function() {
                                            return $("#username").val();

                                        }
                                }
                        },


                },
                username: "required", 
..........
```

I would like the name: 
sent to the remote file where it is converted to a username (lower case remove spaces etc.), checked with other usernames (sql), returned as call back  and then placed in a readonly username input field.
The above shows the callback as required but doesn't input in the form and on submit calls an error to both name and username.

What jquery can I use to fill the username input field with the callback on changing the name?

Comment: What is the question here? _The above shows the callback as required but doesn't input in the form and on submit calls an error to both name and username._

Comment: Sorry the form code didn't show and I have added the question.

Comment: no sure why I lost points on this. It is a perfectly legitimate question.